# Vuex 4 Mutate initial state with the same value doesn't trigger the watcher

Tags: vuejs3, vuex4

So, i try to change the initial state with the same value and the watcher doesn't execute, if the value is different then it works as it is suppose to.

State:

```js
const state = () => ({
  pagination: {
    activePage: 1,
    itemsPerPageOptions: [
      { label: 1, value: 1 },
      { label: 2, value: 2 },
      { label: 3, value: 3 },
      { label: 16, value: 16 },
      { label: 24, value: 24 },
      { label: 32, value: 32 },
      { label: 40, value: 40 },
    ],
    itemsPerPage: 2,
  },
})
```

//For each state i have a getter and a setter(mutation)

```js
const itemsPerPage = computed({
  get: () => store.getters['globals/getItemsPerPage'],
  set: value => store.commit('globals/setItemsPerPage', value),
})

let activePage = computed({
  get: () => store.getters['globals/getActivePage'],
  set: value => store.commit('globals/setActivePage', value),
})

watch(itemsPerPage, () => {
  //some work

  store.commit('globals/setActivePage', 1)
  //or change the computed prop directly with activePage.value = 1
})
```

In the component above, when the itemPerPage value changes, i reset the pagination by setting the activePage to 1.
In another component i have a watcher that retrieves the data from the server based on the activePage:

```js
watch(activePage, page => {
  //get data from server
})
```

It doesn't work like this, but if i change the initial state of activePage to 2, then it works so i'm thinking, maybe, there is a way to force this?

Answer (score 0):

Well, watcher only triggers if the value it is watching changes. Setting the `ref` (or computed writable ref) with value of 1 to 1 will never run a watcher and there is no way to force it...

As I understand it, your watcher responsible for retrieving the data from the server should be triggered by change of both `activePage` **and** `itemsPerPage` (because I bet it using both of these values to get the right data...)

Luckily for you `watch` allows [watching multiple sources](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/reactivity-computed-watchers.html#watching-multiple-sources)

```js
watch([activePage, itemsPerPage] , (newValues) => {
  // newValues[0] = new value of activePage
  // newValues[1] = new value of itemsPerPage

  // or with destructuring
  [newActivePage, newItemsPerPage] = newValues
  
  // ...get data from server
})
```

#### Update

> Right, but the thing is that i end up sending two requests

Well, that must be something else in your code not shown in the question. If you take a look at example below, 2nd watcher is executed only once (sure, my example is not using Vuex but that should not make a difference)

```js
const app = Vue.createApp({
  setup() {
    const activePage = Vue.ref(1)
    const itemsPerPage = Vue.ref(10)

    Vue.watch(itemsPerPage, (value) => {
      console.log(`itemsPerPage changed: ${value}`)
      activePage.value = 1
    })

    Vue.watch([itemsPerPage, activePage], (newValues) => {
      [newItemsPerPage, newActivePage] = newValues
      console.log(`Requesting data from server (itemsPerPage: ${newItemsPerPage}, activePage: ${newActivePage})`)
    })

    Vue.onUpdated(() => console.log(`component updated`))

    return {
      activePage,
      itemsPerPage,
    }
  }
})
app.mount("#app")
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/3.0.11/vue.global.prod.js" integrity="sha512-v+zXKcc6SpL6LiZLwCzxijGutXrQ4tulM1X1IRWchA8gliet94/xz3OWeXDgEyPkvS3MLxwKwpceuJoUBc9Wxg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div> activePage: {{ activePage }} </div>
  <div> <button @click="activePage++">Update activePage</button></div>
  <div> itemsPerPage: {{ itemsPerPage }} </div>
  <div> <button @click="itemsPerPage++">Update itemsPerPage</button></div>
</div>
```

> Just an idea: you want to reset `activePage` to 1 whenever `itemsPerPage` changes. But why do this with watcher when you can make this logic part of the `globals/setItemsPerPage` mutation ?

> There are some other things to be done when the `itemsPerPange` gets changed, but even if there wasn't, what difference would that make?

The big difference is that both changes happen at the same time, not in two independent watchers. It is also much clearer for a future programmer as he immediately sees what is happening.

You can still keep the 1st watcher (to do "other things"), just move the `activePage` mutation to `globals/setItemsPerPage`

#### Hack

Just to be complete - here is a solution **I do not like and recommend** but you will find it in many "reactivity issue" answers here on SO.

Just create helper variable - for example `key = 0`. Whenever you reset the `activePage` to 1, increment `key` by 1. In your second watcher, watch both `activePage` and `key`

Comment: Right, but the thing is that i end up sending two requests in a case where the activePage is different than 1 and the user changes the itemsPerPage. Then itemsPerPage watcher gets triggered, which reset the activePage to 1 and because the active page is different, the activePage&itemsPerPage watcher gets fired twice. So i'm in a bit of a pickle...

Comment: Hmm, I see. Just an idea: you want to reset `activePage` to 1 whenever `itemsPerPage` changes. But why do this with watcher when you can make this logic part of the `globals/setItemsPerPage` mutation ?

Comment: There are some other things to be done when the itemsPerPange gets changed, but even if there wasn't, what difference would that make? On the activePage watcher is where i get the data from the server based on activePage and itemsPerPage. If the activePage is 5 and the user changes itemsPerPage from 16 to 32, maybe there won't be 5 page anymore, and so i need to reset it to 1. But if the activePage is 1 the activePage watcher won't fire. I did fixed the data retrieval in the same way as your response, but that added the duplicate request issue.

Comment: first let me say that i really appreciate all of your work and i'm sorry for my late response, i've been stuck with some things for the past few days.

Comment: I initially had 2 watchers, 1 for activePage and 1 for itemsPerPage in a different component where i also mutate the activePage state. On the activePage watcher i retrieve my data, but since i changed it with [activePage, itemsPerPage], when the activePage is different than 1 and i change itemsPerPage, the itemsPerPage Watcher gets triggered AND also [activePage, itemsPerPage] Watcher and then changes activePage to 1 which triggers AGAIN [activePage, itemsPerPage] watcher

Answer (score 0):

If you want your watcher to run immediatly you can add a second parameter to your watcher which would look like this:

```
watch(() => {...}, {immediate: true})
```

This would run your watcher right at the beginning. So If you would already have your value added and it runs again it should take the exact same value as `newValue`.

If you want it to be a common "process" to run your watcher when the value is set to the exact same value you would need something like an helper function, which Michal already suggested.